# Add reporting service point role to site on SCCM via .Net

Tags: c#, sccm

I would like to add a new role to a site on SCCM programmatically (using C#).
Any help, advice or suggestion will be very useful.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft MSDN Documentation has sample code for deploying a Site System Role, see below link from Microsoft MSDN: 
How to Deploy a Site System Role:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949636.aspx
To get the property names of the role added, you can add a Reporting Service point manually and using code to get the embedded property names.